# spacy regex with japanese characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, spacy, spacy-3

i need help with regex in spacy in japanese. I have this text:
道が凍っているから気を付けなさい。
I need to find match every word until the character "を" in japanese, so essentially i need to get "道が凍っているから気を" . I tried this code:

```
nlp =spacy.load("ja_core_news_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocable)
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^.*?[を]"}}]
matcher.add("mypattern", [pattern])
​doc = nlp(Verbwithnoun)
matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] 
print(doc[start:end)
```

But it prints me nothing, but when i try this pattern "^.*?[を]" on different python regex test site like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [Pythex](https://pythex.org/) it works perfectly, it returns me the correct sentence. But in spacy it doesn't work. It prints nothing. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: The regex you are using in `TEXT` only applies to each token, not to the whole `doc`ument.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much, i just finished reading the documentation, you're right. But is there another way to get all characters before "を"?

Comment: Maybe you want just `doc = nlp(Verbwithnoun[:Verbwithnoun.find("を")+1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wiktor noted, the Matcher matches against tokens, not the whole sentence. Assuming you only want to match on the object marker `を` and not words like `ををがけ` or something you can just walk the tokens.

```
def until_wo(doc):
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.text == 'を':
            return doc[0:tok.i]

text = "..."
doc = nlp(text)
print(until_wo(doc))
```

Comment: As always thank you!